# $pull is not pulling elements from nested array structure

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to pull an element from an array of objects having following structure:

```
{
    "tasks" : [
        {
            "maintask" : "Walk",
            "subtask" : [
                {
                    "task_name" : "1/2 hour walk",
                    "photo_urls" : [
                        {
                            "photo_url" : "banner1.jpeg",
                        },
                        {
                            "photo_url" : "banner.jpeg",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

And I need to delete the object based upon photo_url. I am executing following query to remove a photo_url object from photo_urls array:

```
db.booking_checklist.update({}, 
{$pull: {tasks: {subtask: {photo_urls: {$elemMatch: {photo_url: {$regex: ".*banner1.jpeg.*"}}}}}}})
```

This query match the object but does not modify it. following is the response of the query:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

I am also trying for another query but that query is vanishing whole task object:

```
db.booking_checklist.update({}, 
{$pull: {tasks: {"subtask.photo_urls": {$elemMatch: {photo_url: {$regex: ".*banner1.jpeg.*"}}}}}})
```

I am stuck into this from past few hours. Please tell how should I approach this..

Comment: Use `db.booking_checklist.update({},{$pull: { "tasks.$[].subtask.$[].photo_urls": {photo_url: {$regex: ".*banner1.jpeg.*"}} } })`

Comment: @Veeram, thank you so much. You saved my time.